# Insert an image into ANX format, IBM Chart Reader and I2 Analyst

Tags: javascript, python, java, base64, websphere

I am trying to insert an image inside an anx file to be able to view it in IBM i2 or their Chart reader.
Reading the documentation (openly available, downloading the Chart reader) I see this
[image]

I go to insert the required fields and I do not receive any error, but the displayed image is transparent.

Is there anyone who has an anx file in which there is an image so that I can understand where am I wrong?

Can someone give me an example of how to fill in these fields?